# MySQL - Insert data and select from table

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using MySQL to insert data manually to my database for learning purposes and I've stumbled across a slight confusion amongst one part, which I thought I cracked after reading a topic on here, however it doesn't insert anything but doesn't give an error either.

Here's the code that I've entered which returns no errors but does nothing either:

```
INSERT INTO Deliveries (O_ID,ShipDate,ArrDate,Del_Comp)
SELECT O_ID,'2012-10-21','2012-11-02','City Link'
FROM Orders
WHERE O_ID=1;
```

What I'm basically trying to do, is select an ID from the `Orders` table (preferably a wildcard if possible), and then add custom information in the same row before adding it to the `Deliveries` table. So I'll obviously end up with my first row being all the information that's on the SELECT row.

Comment: Do you definitely have an row in Orders with an O_ID of 1?

Comment: So you want to UPDATE and existing row!?!

Comment: O_ID is the primary key in my Orders table, so yes it does exist. And no Strawberry, I want to insert a new row in my Deliveries table.

Comment: Why the SELECT? You want to copy a row from Orders?

Comment: No, I don't want to copy a row. Just 1 field from a row from Orders, and then add new information into the row in the Deliveries table.

Comment: @MattVon What is the problem with the code you posted it should work fine?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't insert any information at all, which is what I don't get. =/

Answer (score 1):

The part which is wrong is `SELECT O_ID,'2012-10-21','2012-11-02','City Link'` which gives a combination of INSERT using values and INSERT using SELECT subquery.

You want to specify column names to SELECT, not actual values.

Comment: Okay, you are on the right tracks of what I want. The values I've manually added don't currently exist at the moment. O_ID does in the Orders table, but the rest of the information doesn't. This is what I'm trying to do, collect one item from a row from one table, and combine it with new values that are manually entered (not collected from another table).

Comment: See Mahmoud Gamal's answer. It works. Just tested it. Initially I didn't get what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like he just deleted his post. The code isn't working for me at all. It states there's no syntax errors or anything, but it's not inserting anything for me either.